# How to run system() as administrator in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, admin

I need to send some commands as system admin throught PHP `system()` function on Windows environment.

I know that it can be dangerous, but I need that.

Comment: It depends on how you use it, please provide further details, and what "commands" you want to run.

Comment: are you an admin? so what is the question you need to know the syntax?

Comment: I'm running PHP in local environment with Apache. 
The question is: how to run commands as admin in Prompt by using system()?

Without PHP I could open Prompt as Administrator and run my commands, but in PHP how should I do this?

The command that I should run is "net user xx xx /add"

Comment: @Syncro have you tried it `system('net user xx xx /add')` what happened?

Comment: It fails because I'm not admin.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by using a toolkit named [cpau](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/)

By using it I can exec command very simply:

```
cpau -u administrator -p PWD_HERE -LWP -ex "net user myuser mypwd /add"
```

To make this work I've needed to change my Administrator password in Computer Management > Users.

**For those people saying "use runas"**

I could not use `runas` because it prompts for a password and I can't pass it in the same command line.

PS: Remember to place `cpau` in PHP folder.